# "PUT" request fails with Mongoose in NextJS 13 application

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to make a simple game app in **NextJS 13** with user authentication that is connected to a **MongoDB** database.

My authentication works fine, I can register and log in. I manage to do this using **Mongoose** and **NextAuth**.

After login the game dashboard loads and you can play as the logged in user. After playing I want to update the user's funds in the **MongoDB** database with a *"PUT"* request but it fails with a *404 status* code.

API route for the *"PUT"*

```
export async function PUT(request, { params }) {
    const { id } = params
    const { newFunds: funds } = await request.json()
    await connectMongoDB()
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { funds })
    return NextResponse.json({message:"Funds updtaed"}, {status:200})
}
```

my User model

```
import mongoose, { Schema, models } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    funds: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
  },
);

const User = models.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;
```

I am using a *useEffect* hook to update after every round of the game

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (initRender && newFunds === initFunds) {
      initRender.current = false
    } else {
      console.log("fetch")
      fetch(`api/users/${user._id}`,{
        method: "PUT",
        headers : {
          "Content-type" : "application/json",
        },
        body : JSON.stringify({newFunds}),
      }
      )
    }
  }, [newFunds])
```

I have other API routes and request to this database that are working perfecltly, like *"GET"* for getting users and *"POST"* for registration.

Here is the full source code for more context : [GitHub repo](https://github.com/petruskatamas/rising-stack-game)

I tried to check the fetch with **Postman** but it fails there too. I tried to modify the API route to query on other params but that failed too.

Checked the **Mongoose** docs, but  I couldn't figure out the problem, looking at that this should work.

*SOLVED*

In my `@lib/mongodb.js` I needed to export the function as default...